# Is the logistic map $x_{n+1}=r x_n (1-x_n)$ exactly solvable for any $r$ other than $-2,2,4$?

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, integrable-systems, chaos, discrete-dynamical-systems

It is [known](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html) that for $r=-2,2,4$ the logistic map $x_{n+1}=r x_n (1-x_n)$ has exact solutions of the form
$$
x_n=\frac12 \left\{ 1- f\left(r^n f^{-1}(1-2x_0)\right)\right\} \qquad \qquad{(*)}
$$
for suitable functions $f$. The same source further claims, with reference to a private communication, that $r=-2,2,4$ are the only values of $r$ for which the logistic map has exact solutions of the form $(*)$.

However, one wonders whether

> are there other values of $r$ for which the logistic map is exactly solvable?

Of course, for these other values of $r$, if any, the exact solutions would likely be of the form other than (*); alas so far I found in the literature nothing that would answer the above question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explicit solutions for arbitrary $r$ exist in various forms:

- [Logistic map: an
  analytical solution](http://havlin.biu.ac.il/PS/rbbsh260.pdf) (1995) represents the solution as a power of
  a transfer matrix.
- [An explicit solution
  for the logistic map](http://havlin.biu.ac.il/PS/rmh365.pdf) (1999) gives a functional integral solution.
- [A note on
  exact solutions of the logistic map](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5125097) (2020, paywall) gives the
  solution in terms of a power series.

Comment: Thank you. Exploring the citations to the first of your references I have also found a paper giving the exact solution in the form of a determinant for any $r$: 

M Bruschi, Determinantal solution of the logistic map, J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. 31 (1998) L153-L155 https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/31/7/003